# Объяснение работы скрипта

Tags: javascript

С помощью этого кода создается индикатор загрузки. Кто-нибудь может объяснить порядок JS-кода в функции race? Почему setTimeout стоит именно там, а не в другом месте?
И еще, можете посоветовать статьи, книги, видео, объясняющие порядок работы кода в теле функции? Мне хочется писать осмысленный код, где я понимаю каждую строчку кода.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loa"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
div {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.tim {
    width: 15px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #0000cc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

```
addEventListener('load', race);

let i = 0;
let d = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

function race() {
    let t = '';
    
    for (let a = 0; a <= d[i]; a++) {
        t+= "<div class='tim'></div>";
    }

    document.getElementById('loa').innerHTML = t;
    i++;
    
    if (i == d.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(race, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Ну конкретно тут её можно написать в любом месте функции race. Но в конце логичнее, мы как бы говорим: «эта итерация закончилась, а через секунду повторим».

Comment: порядок работы кода в теле функции — сверху вниз. Или в чём вопрос?

Comment: Мне уже написали, что setTimeout можно написать выше и всё она отработает так, как надо. Короче, не понимаю работу функции из-за того, что в race есть много всего — цикл for, функция setTimeout. проверка условия if, из-за чего не понимаю в какой последовательности всё это надо писать. Но ниже также написали, что сначала нужно подсчитать и нарисовать и только потом на следующей итерации вызвать setTimeout.
По собственной инициативе копаюсь в JS и не понимаю многих базисных вещей.

Comment: А можете объяснить каждую строчку в функции race, что она делает и выполняет?

Answer (score 2):

> Почему setTimeout стоит именно там, а не в другом месте?

Потому что надо сделать все вычисления, всё перевысчитать, перерисовать и **только потом** заново вызвать эту функцию. Было бы странно перевызывать эту функцию **до** каких-либо вычислений и перерисовок

Банально таймаут может сработать раньше, чем произойдут все вычисления и перерисовка, так как может браузер слабый, железка хилая, факторов, которые притормозят - много. Поэтому даже в игровых движках (например Unity3d) есть специальная функция и свойство `Time.deltaTime`, которая возвращает 'мс' с последнего фрейма, чтобы это значение вставить в вычисления для компенсации, чтобы у всех пользователей работало одинаково на любых железках. Поэтому угадать с таймаутом заранее просто невозможно.

Comment: Не было бы странно) Можно писать вызов `setTimeout` и в начале ф-ии `race`, отработает так же. Просто так выглядит логичнее

Comment: Можно не суметь высчитать нужное количество миллисекунд для срабатывания, т.к. интернет у всех всегда разный. Поэтом логичнее поместить в конец, когда точно всё отработает

Comment: Ну тут и нет таких подводных камней, связанных с интернетом) Идут обычные вычисления, даже если он написал бы там 0 вместо 1000, то ф-ия вызвалась бы только на следующей итерации, а к тому моменту уже вычислнения закончатся)

Comment: Не стоит так надеятся. Интернет ли, может браузер слабый, железка хилая, факторов, которые притормозят - много. Поэтому даже в игровых движках (например Unity3d) есть специальная функция и свойство `Time.deltaTime` которая возвращает 'мс' с последнего фрейма, чтобы это значение вставить в вычисления для компенсации, чтобы у всех пользователей работало одинаково на любых железках.

Comment: Резонно, тоже писал через эту ф-ию когда делал игры) Но когда начал изучать GameDev в JS, то читая доки увидел, что рекомендуют вызывать перерисовку в начале ф-ии https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Anatomy#building_a_main_loop_in_javascript

Comment: Это requestAnimationFrame, это другое. Если округлить (сейчас меня все запинают за сравнение), то это тот же таймаут, только с 1мс задержкой  в конце функции.  Но в целом сравнивать requestAnimationFrame и таймаут нельзя. Таймаут вообще для перерисовки, особенно на каком-нибудь canvase и для игр не годится в принципе.

Comment: Ну до этой фичи так и писали) Да и полифилы тоже на setTimeout завязаны. Суть в том что вызов перерисовки будет, когда удобно браузеру. Типа вычислил раньше чем 10мс (60fps по крайней мере он вроде туда целится), молодец, жди пока я доберусь до тебя, если вычисления идут дольше то он уже тормозит перерисовку и получаются лаги)

Comment: Раньше и на охоту с копьями ходили. Сейчас же совсем очевидно, что проще слона из ружья подстрелить, потому что эффективнее по всем параметрам, чем компьём тыкать)) Но да,если хочется острых ощущений - то можно и с вилкой на тигра))

Comment: Нашёл до чего докапаться Давай не тебе не мне: Всё зависит от поставленной задачи) (Безумно можно быть первым!)